# Ember 2.10.x Passing elemendId from Child Component to Parent Component throughs Action (Popover)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, popup

Given the following Code:

```
{{#my-popover tagName="i" title="Wirklich löschen?" classNames="fa fa-times red-text"}}
<button  class="btn btn-warning" {{action 'removeRecord'}}>Delete it!</button>
{{/my-popover}}
```

I need the generated elemendId from the component my-popover to close the Popover after delete the record within the parent components action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to yield `elementId` from `my-popover` component to parent component.

Created [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ea2a791ed4465b2c715f6eb3b7c256e6?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-popover.hbs) for you.

my-popover.hbs : I am yielding elementId property to caller

```
{{yield elementId}}
```

application.hbs : getting elementId from my-popover component and passing it to removeRecord function.

```
{{#my-popover tagName="i" title="Wirklich löschen?" classNames="fa fa-times red-text" as |elementId|}}
<button  class="btn btn-warning" {{action 'removeRecord' elementId}}>Delete it!</button>
{{/my-popover}}
```

application.js :

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  actions:{
    removeRecord(elementId){
      console.log('removeRecord in application ',elementId);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's nice! It is the power of the contextual components.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the generated elemendId as the second parameter in the sendAction method of your `my-popover.js` file.

Example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    doSomething(){
        this.sendAction("doSomething", this.get('elemendId'));
    }
  }
});
```